# Produtor e Consumidor em Java com mesma taxa de produção e consumo, apesar de velocidades diferentes

Tags: java, design-pattern, threadpool

Olá!

Estou iniciando uso de `BlockingQueue` e `ExecutorService` para implementar um Produtor-Consumidor.

Olhando a página https://is.gd/BcIIXK, removi a linha 24, e mudei a linha 38 para `Thread.sleep(3000);`, para que o produtor fosse mais rápido que o consumidor.

Mas o resultado foi:

```
Produced 0
Produced 1
Produced 2
Consume 0
Consume 1
Produced 3
Consume 2
Produced 4
Consume 3
Produced 5
Consume 4
Produced 6
```

Ou seja, depois que o consumidor rodou a primeira vez, tanto ele quanto o produtor pararam pelo mesmo sleep.

Lendo o help da `ExecutorService::execute`, temos:

> Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.

Parece que tanto `producerTask` e `consumerTask` estão rodando na mesma thread.

Alguém saberia como forçar que rodem em threads separadas, para que a velocidade de produção seja, de fato, diferente da de consumo?

Obrigado

Comment: Os dois estarem rodando no mesmo thread não é possível porque os dois estão em loop. São dois loops para uma thread só executar mesmo tempo, não dá. Você pode imprimir os nomes das threads (`Thread.currentThread().getName()`) para se certificar disso.

Comment: Só sugestões dadas por cima, experimente trocar por uma fila bloqueante que não tenha tamanho fixo ou então aumentar a capacidade da fila bloqueante. Pesquise as classes que implementam a interface `BlockingQueue`. Imprimir o `size()` da fila também pode ajudar a entender o que acontece.

Comment: Só lembrando que como o próprio nome diz a fila é bloqueante, ou seja, quando você tenta fazer `put(item)`  (ou `add(item)`, não lembro) com ela cheia ou `poll()` com ela vazia ela bloqueia até ter condições de atender a solicitação.

Comment: Parece que a segunda sugestão explica